# Bluetooth headset not working in 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have a Lenovo laptop, on which I run Ubuntu. I have a pair of bluetooth headphones which I have used with the laptop for some time, without problems. Now I have updated to 20.04, and the headphones do not work: I have checked that i) bluetooth is working, ii) the pulseaudio and pulseaudio-module-blutooth module are installed, iii) bluetooth sees the headphones, and iv) the computer thinks it is sending audio to bluetooth, but the sound actually comes out through the laptop speakers.

```
systemctl status bluetooth says this:
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-04-25 13:18:52 BST; 22min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 11368 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9341)
     Memory: 1.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─11368 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 25 13:18:52 malebranche bluetoothd[11368]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Apr 25 13:18:52 malebranche systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Apr 25 13:18:52 malebranche bluetoothd[11368]: Starting SDP server
Apr 25 13:18:52 malebranche bluetoothd[11368]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Apr 25 13:18:52 malebranche bluetoothd[11368]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.173 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Apr 25 13:18:52 malebranche bluetoothd[11368]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.173 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Apr 25 13:19:45 malebranche bluetoothd[11368]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E8_07_BF_04_1B_D0/sep1/fd0: fd(38) ready
Apr 25 13:21:35 malebranche bluetoothd[11368]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E8_07_BF_04_1B_D0/sep1/fd1: fd(53) ready
Apr 25 13:30:53 malebranche bluetoothd[11368]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Apr 25 13:31:09 malebranche bluetoothd[11368]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E8_07_BF_04_1B_D0/sep1/fd2: fd(53) ready
```

However, the sound settings panel says that the sound output is through the headset, but when I press the "test" button, sound comes out through the laptop speakers. This happens both when the configuration is A2DP or HSP/HFP  So, the GUI says that all is well, whereas systemctl status says that something is going wrong.

Comment: Me also encountered same problem but occasionally, removing device and pairing again helps me

Comment: Having the same issue on two separate installations of 20.04:  a Lenovo laptop and an HP desktop. Sounds plays from the laptop speakers or the desktop speakers when the bluetoth headset is selected in Sound Settings. This occurs with the "test" buttons and with audio from Firefox. However, when I use the volume hotkeys I can hear the volume indicator getting louder or softer in the headphones. Reconnecting the headphones or restarting bluetooth has allowed me to hear audio from games in Steam, but nothing else. Headphones worked fine on both devices before I upgraded from 19.10.

Comment: Ah. My headphones are called GTCBTNC16, and in syslog it says that this device "is tagged by udev as: Keyboard". This explains a lot of bad behaviour.

Comment: Same think upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. My Bluetooth headset was working fine before with my laptop but not anymore. Also, I'm not sure it is related directly to Bluetooth because I have the same problem with a USB Radio gaming headset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 no sound out of Bluetooth headphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232159/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound-out-of-bluetooth-headphones)

Comment: Yes Sudhakar. I do the same with my Tzumi earbuds. The a2dp driver should be loaded automatically when the device is connected.
But try disconnecting/reconnecting. It's faster. It's a pulseaudio bug being fixed.
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/merge_requests/298

Comment: This worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1243890/282918

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same situation upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04 with a HP laptop and Skullcandy Bluetooth headphones: Using the sound panel and changing the output to the headphone does not work. However using the pulse-audio volume control and switching the output to the headphone redirect the sound to them.

Pulse audio should be installed but in case it is not:

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

To the Ubuntu team: that is a bug to be fixed.

Cheer!