# Firefox issues in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: firefox, 20.04, lts

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 with TDE (unofficially) and everything works out of the box. The only issue I'm having is with Firefox (version 76), which works just fine but there's a few issues. For one, the browser has no sound. Second, I have Ublock Origin and it doesn't seem to block any ads like it did previously. I tried to click on it but the GUI that opens when you click on the extension is choppier than I remember and opens to show "?" requests blocked.  Third, loading some websites such as Twitch or MEGA for example result in a "Gah! Your tab just crashed." message. Is there a remedy to this?

Answer (score 0):

While installing Ubuntu 20.04 on my device i had the same Firefox issue, a reboot fixed that.
For the issue with the sound refer to [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232159/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound-out-of-bluetooth-headphones) if its only broken with Bluetooth devices.