# Headset Microphone is not detected on Ubuntu 20.04 on Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, dell, microphone

A Bluetooth Headset Speaker is working fine but microphone is not shown in the input list in sound setting. By default it used built-in laptop microphone.
I have tried a lots of AskUbuntu answers but nothing worked for me.

Comment: "*I have tried a lots of AskUbuntu answers but nothing worked for me.*" Without knowing what you've done so far, we are ill-prepared to help you continue with your troubleshooting.  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1263176/edit) your question and tell us exactly what you've tried so far and provide the detailed results of each attempts.  The work you've already done has probably already hinted at some solution - so share your work with us.

Comment: see this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242249/headset-microphone-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04