# Combo Jack External Microphone

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headphones

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 on an 8th Gen Core i5 Acer Aspire E5-576G. The laptop has a combo jack that works properly on Windows.

When I plug a device into the audio jack on Windows, it lets me choose whether it should treat it as a microphone, speaker, headphones, headset, line in, etc. However, when I boot into Ubuntu, the only options I find are headphones and headset.

[Ubuntu 21.04 Select Audio Device Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qymzM.jpg)

I've seen in another [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00fhAW7qYQk) that there is supposed to be an option for Microphone, such that **when I plug an external microphone into the laptop, the built in speakers still work**. Since headset and headphones are the only options presented on my laptop, when I plug a device into the combo jack, it makes the built in speakers *unavailable*, even on `pavucontrol`.

[Ubuntu 16.04 Select Audio Device Image - with Microphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNgKf.jpg)

I've tried the solution in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242249/headset-microphone-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04) which involves adding the following lines to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-hda-intel position fix=1
options snd-hda-intel model=<model>
```

Where `<model>` is the sound card model that matches the laptop according to this website.

This doesn't work though to add the microphone option in my laptop. Would this even be possible?