# Sound problem in Huawei laptop with Conexant CX8070 chip

Tags: drivers, sound, alsa, headphones, huawei

My laptop is a Huawei MDZ-WXX9X, with the sound chip Conexant CX8070, and I'm running ubuntu 22.04.
I'm encountering the following two problems:

1. the sound is horrible in comparison to windows (I've
   dual-boot).
2. when I plug a Jack cable, the sound becomes normal, but the output comes both from the laptop's speaker and the headphones.

I've tried to assign the model of the card sound that I have to this `options snd-hda-intel model=MODEL` in the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`, like what they said [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto), but I didn't find `Conexant CX8070` in `/usr/share/doc/alsa-base/driver/HD-Audio-Models.txt.gz`.
I also tried to assign `laptop`, which is the basic laptop config (default), but I still have the same problem.

here is the output of `sudo lspci -v`:

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Device 1e83:3e35
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 186, IOMMU group 12
    Memory at 601d1b0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 601d000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some workarounds listed here:
https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/3350
The general consensus seems to wait for a kernel patch

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, I'll try once I can and I'll let you know