Bluetooth Headphone Input not working after move to 24.04
My bluetooth headphones worked fine on 23.10 on two different machines. One of them I did the upgrade to 24.04 and they still work for input and output.
The other machine failed the upgrade, so I had to do a clean install of 24.04. On that machine the headphones work to play sound, but don't show up Mic input in settings. To be specific, on the upgrade machine, "pw-cli ls |grep -i blue" shows
    object.path = "bluez_output.A8_99_DC_1F_CA_8E.1:monitor_0"
    device.api = "bluez5"
    device.name = "bluez_card.A8_99_DC_1F_CA_8E"
    object.path = "bluez_output.A8_99_DC_1F_CA_8E.1:playback_0"
    node.name = "bluez_input.A8_99_DC_1F_CA_8E.0"
    object.path = "bluez_input.A8_99_DC_1F_CA_8E.0:capture_0"
    node.name = "bluez_output.A8_99_DC_1F_CA_8E.1"

On the clean install machine
    object.path = "bluez_output.A8_99_DC_1F_CA_8E.1:monitor_0"
    object.path = "bluez_output.A8_99_DC_1F_CA_8E.1:monitor_1"
    object.path = "bluez_output.A8_99_DC_1F_CA_8E.1:playback_0"
    device.api = "bluez5"
    device.name = "bluez_card.A8_99_DC_1F_CA_8E"
    object.path = "bluez_output.A8_99_DC_1F_CA_8E.1:playback_1"
    node.name = "bluez_output.A8_99_DC_1F_CA_8E.1"

Notice no input. Any ideas?

I have exactly this problem too - basically I gave up.  I'd really like an answer that explains how to debug the connection.  There's so little information and "dumbed down" user interfaces in Ubuntu now, that all you can do is keep clicking "connect" like a monkey.

Have you tried these? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242249/headset-microphone-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-20-04

Well the problem solved itself. I had to reboot for unrelated reasons, and after the boot the mic side of the bluetooth headphone was recognized.
