# 20.04 Sony WH-1000XM4 does not output to headset

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, headset

I have a Sony WH-1000XM4 which is paired to Ubuntu 20.04.
The output is configured to the headset, but the sound keep coming out from the speaker instead.

Bluez was already installed:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ bluetoothctl --version
bluetoothctl: 5.53
```

I have tried to disconnect, connect again, reboot Bluetooth, but it still doesn't work.
I have also installed the following libraries:

```
sudo apt install libdbus-1-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev
```

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution here

[Ubuntu 20.04 no sound out of Bluetooth headphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232159/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound-out-of-bluetooth-headphones)

```
mv ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse.old
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
```

Worked!