# Sony Noise-Cancelling Headphones are not recognized as audio output(WH-1000XM4)

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, headphones

I'm trying to use Sony WH-1000XM4 with my Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm able to pair using a Bluetooth dongle and blueman, but the problem is that the headphones are not recognized as a sound device:

- In blueman - right click doesn't show "audio" options.
- In pulse audio - the headphones don't appear in the output devices.

I already tried:

```
mv ~/.config/pulse/ ~/.config/pulse.old
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
```

as suggested at [20-04-sony-wh-1000xm4-does-not-output-to-headset](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285419/20-04-sony-wh-1000xm4-does-not-output-to-headset)

and the solution at [Sony Noise-Cancelling Headphones (WH-1000XM2/3) and bluetooth initial autoconnect](https://askubuntu.com/q/1139404/555180)

so far, nothing works.

How can I find what's the problem and fix?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order to correctly pair Ubuntu with the headphones, you need to put them in pairing mode. (not needed when pairing other devices)

Hold power button for 7 second (even after it says power off), until you hear pairing mode.

Then, Ubuntu's Bluetooth will recognize an audio device named **WH-1000XM4** (not LE_WH-1000XM4), and it will work.
more details [here](https://helpguide.sony.net/mdr/wh1000xm4/v1/en/contents/TP0002752780.html).

Comment: Thank you!!! I spent hours trying to debug why my headphones wouldn't connect (other Bluetooth devices worked) this was the answer!

Comment: The same procedure works for WH-1000XM5 as well

Comment: I had to enable A2DP with blueman after this so that I was not stuck in mono sound.

Comment: Thanks that's help me for WH-1000XM5

Comment: Finally! "not LE_WH..." was the key.

Answer (score 0):

The same is true for the Sony earphones like WF-1000XM3/4/5. They need to be connected in pairing mode, too. Otherwise the "LE" will not be reckognized as an audio device (i. e. headset), just as "unknown". Seems to be a linux bluetooth stack issue. Connecting to a windows 11 computer works flawlessly.