# bluetooth not working ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have the Sony wf-1000xm3 and my Bluetooth settings appear that I'm connected to the earbuds. However I have no audio output and it's not really paired since these Sony earbuds play a message of Bluetooth connected once the Bluetooth is correctly connected.

When I go terminal and hit the command `pulseaudio` I get this message:

```
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

I tried this already [Ubuntu 20.04 no sound out of Bluetooth headphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232159/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound-out-of-bluetooth-headphones) but maybe there is something wrong with my `pulseaudio`.