# Bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 20.04 even after showing active in systemctl

Tags: drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, ralink, bluez

Hello Ubuntu community!
A newbie Ubuntu user here, and this is officially my first post in StackExchange.

As the title mentioned, Bluetooth is not working and through *Settings*, I cannot enable it. It seems that Ubuntu could not detect the Bluetooth driver.

[image: printscreen of bluetooth not being detected in "settings"]

Solutions which I have tried:

1. Reinstalling Bluez and restarting + a complete shutdown (pulling out the power cord, waiting for a few seconds before inserting back in and firing up my HP Pavilion 15-n200 laptop)
2. Tried `sudo rmmod btusb` + `sudo modprobe btusb` + checking status of Bluetooth with `systemctl`. Seems to be activated, but again, I cannot switch on my Bluetooth through the *Settings*

   [image: Showing "Active" status in systemctl for bluetooth]
3. Tried `rfkill unblock bluetooth`, without any luck

   [image: Showing the result of rfkill unblock bluetooth]

I've read that there might be an issue linked with Python 3.7.

Source: [Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working)

I have already confirmed my Python is currently on 3.8:

[image: Screenshot proving the current Python version is 3.8]

Read that there's a bug related to pulseaudio in Ubuntu 20.04,
where old config values have not been cleared and it is not routing to the correct device.

It was mentioned that the solution is to delete the old config and restart pulseaudio, which I did, and rebooted my laptop, but still no luck in getting the built-in Bluetooth to work...

Source: [Ubuntu 20.04 no sound out of Bluetooth headphones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232159/ubuntu-20-04-no-sound-out-of-bluetooth-headphones#answer-1233846)

Please let me know if I have violated any of the rules in StackExchange, or there is any lack of information on my side.
Thank you very much for the existence of this helpful community + for this fantastic tool for us newbie to reach out to the community of same interest.

Comment: Hey did you ever find a fix for this? My `systemctl` is showing the same as yours but bluetooth still isnt working.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, with my HP Pavilion 15-N200 laptop, it comes with Ralink bluetooth, RT3290. [Ralink bluetooth adaptor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSCbI.png)
It's not a bad bluetooth adaptor, except for the fact that this Linux kernel module support has been discontinued.
We have to turn to the following for the right solution for those who, like me, owns RT3290 bluetooth adaptor:
Execute the following in your Terminal

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms` (No worries, this is a reliable repo. If you have any doubts, refer to the original source, read and then judge it for yourself: https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms)
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms`
4. `sudo modprobe rtbth` (by now, your bluetooth should be working. Continue with step five to auto-start the bluetooth module every time once you boot-up OS)
5. `sudo nautilus` in your terminal and it will open your File explorer. Inside your file explorer, navigate to `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf` and open it up.
6. Inside `modules.conf`, type in **rtbth** at the bottom of the line (make sure to add in in a newline, not within the `#` line), and save it.
7. Verify that your Bluetooth gets started automatically after reboot.

*I read that there is an issue with the Bluetooth when we try to close our laptop lid. The only way to fix the issue is by rebooting our OS.

Good luck to those of you facing the same problem which I did, and hope this answer will be of use to someone out there =)

Source and references:

- https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms
- https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:1814-3298-105b-e056
- https://webwiks.com/techcorner/get-ralink-rt3290-bluetooth-work-in-linux/