# firefox not playing music on BT headphones

Tags: sound, firefox, bluetooth, headphones

Weird issue I'm struggling to solve.
Headphones work on other browsers, games etc. Audio is properly played.
When I'm using Firefox (YouTube, Spotify, anything else) audio is played on other output device, my laptop speaker for example.
Ubuntu 22.04LTS / Lenovo ThinkPad T14 Gen 1.

Any help will be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Not an answer - sorry, but I have the exact same problem with Firefox.
Strange thing is, is when I select the 'test' button, the test speech is output through the laptop speakers, not the BT Headphones, perhaps hinting at a Linux/Ubuntu bug?

Comment: same problem that I have now on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: maybe this could help you: https://askubuntu.com/a/1233846/1538217